# how to find strings that contain only one special character?

Tags: regex

I have a string, for example:

```
const str = "he**o *ow ar* you ***** ***?"
```

And I want to match only the strings that contain only the asterisks, so the result in this case would be:

```
const output = ["*****", "***"]
```

I thought it would be something like this:

```
const regex = /\b\*+\b/g
```

But I think the word boundary cannot work since * is not a word character.

Regex is definitely not my strong suit, so can anyone help me here please?

Comment: `/(?<!\*)\*+(?!\*)/g` verbose, or simply `/\*+/g`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<=\W)\*+(?=\W)
```

Explanation:
`(?=\W)` and `(?=\W)` behave similar to \b (are zero length assertions, which means they match a position but no specific character. In the same way as \b matches a boundary between a word char and a not word char, `(?=\W)` tells the engine to match a position which is not preceded by a word char and `(?=\W)` a position which is not followed by one. Because you want the whole word to be "*" then it makes sense to match a set of * which is not preceded or followed by any word char.

Working example here:
https://regex101.com/r/TQftpX/1

[image]

usage in javascript:

```
const str = "he**o *ow ar* you ***** ***?";
const output = [... str.matchAll(/(?<=\W)\*+(?=\W)/g)].map(match => match[0]);
//  output === [ "*****", "***" ]
```

Comment: Perfect! All of the answers worked well, but I also really liked your explanation. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use a look arounds for input ends or non-words:

```
(?<=^|\W)\*+(?=$|\W)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/cG49Hc8Kci8Jbi).

This will also match when the all-asterisk word is at either end, eg

```
**** foo ***
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific example data, another option instead of using `\b` might be using `\B`

```
\B\*+\B
```

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/JN85Kr/1)

If you don't want a partial match in for example `a*****` or `*****a` you can make use of lookarounds asserting not `*` to the left and right:

```
\B(?<!\*)\*+\B(?!\*)
```

See another [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/YW21tf/1).